# EC2 host in two TGs - one healthy, one unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an EC2 instance, running a web server. It's up an running and I can connect.

Right now, it's behind an ALB which is forwarding traffic to a TG which has this EC2 instance as its only registered target. The target group is reporting the EC2 instance as healthy, and all is well with the world. This ALB has the necessary cert attached so that I can browse using HTTPS.

Unfortunately, this LB is in the public internet and I no longer want this host to be publicly accessible.

I want to first make it available on our internal network (i.e. on a different LB), before removing the routing rules (or the target group) from the public LB.

So, in other words this host would be accessible via either two separate LBs - one public, one private.

So, I created another target group, same settings, and added the EC2 instance to this second group.

Only in this new group, the host's status is reporting unhealthy - "**Request timed out**".

I've double checked the health check rules (the same for both target groups), and using `curl` I am able to get a response from port 80 (i.e. `curl http://private-ip:80/api/` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`), plus as I mentioned, in the original TG, the host is showing as "**healthy**".

I'm sure I am missing something obvious... but right now, it's eluding me...

**EDIT00**: the EC2 instance is set to allow inbound requests on port 80 and 443.

**EDIT01**: I had thought that I had set it to allow inbound from all (`0.0.0.0/0`), but apparently the attached security groups were not sufficient. Thanks to [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: "the EC2 instance is set to allow inbound requests on port 80 and 443." From what sources?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; The security group(s) defined on the EC2 instance weren't sufficient to allow traffic from the new ALB.

Once I was pointed in the right direction I added (temporarily) a security group allowing ports 80/443 from any source.

Once I applied that and the health checks on both ALBs were succeeding, that was my answer.

Not wanting to leave the EC2 instance that wide open though, I obtained the IP address(es) of the new ALB and amended the SG rules to allow inbound 80/443 only on those IPv4 addresses.

If you need to get the IP address(es) of your ALB, go [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-ip).